# Optimizing ListView adapter to display dynamic content in individual ListView items

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to display a ListView where individual list items feature a dynamic number of elements. Each item list will have a TextView for a date. Following the date, there can be between 2-5 elements featured.

- ListItemA

  - DateTextView
  - 2-5 TextView
- ListItemB

  - DateTextView
  - 2-5 TextView
- ListItemC

  - DateTextView
  - 2-5 TextView

...

With this current method, it displays the blank TextViews at the bottom of the ListView's item. Would there be a better way to do this?

I thought that `convertView` would have had methods to add layout elements to it, but that's not the case.

Adapter's getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ViewHolder holder;


    if(convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);

        holder.text_date_cashout = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_date_cashout);

        holder.dynamic_views.add((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_cashout1));
        holder.dynamic_views.add((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_cashout2));
        holder.dynamic_views.add((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_cashout3));
        holder.dynamic_views.add((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_cashout4));
        holder.dynamic_views.add((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_cashout5));

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //get and set date from current cashOutHistory
    CashOutHistory coh = cashOutHistory.get(position);
    holder.text_date_cashout.setText(coh.getDate());

    //loop individual cashOuts to display their values
    int i = 0;
    for (CashOut co : coh.getCashOutHistory() ){
        holder.dynamic_views.get(i).setText(co.toString());
        i++;
    }

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    TextView text_date_cashout;
    ArrayList<TextView> dynamic_views = new ArrayList<TextView>(5);
}
```

List item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/text_date_cashout" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/text_cashout1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/text_cashout2" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/text_cashout3" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/text_cashout4" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/text_cashout5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit #1**

Loop showing and hidding the TextViews in my list item:

```
//loop individual cashOuts to display their values
int i = 0;
for (CashOut co : coh.getCashOutHistory() ){
    holder.dynamic_views.get(i).setText(co.toString());
    i++;
}

while(i < 5){
    holder.dynamic_views.get(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Can't you set `.setVisibility(View.GONE);` on each of your `TextView`s that aren't required to be displayed for that particular item?

Comment: @leigh never occurred to me that I could do this. Implementing now.

Comment: Remember to set it back to visible from getView if you need it(in other words rememer about that view can be reused)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide each view you don't need showing for that particular item by using:

```
Boolean someCondition = true;

if (someCondition)
    holder.dynamic_views.get(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, the rest is a valid implementation for what I want to do? It seems to work great ATM. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely, your other option is to create another `layout_list_item.xml` and determine which to `inflate` in your `getView` but I really don't think you need to do that.